# Why is "attempted to set private field on non-instance only" error firing when using a data member and not when using a local variable?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm writing a class using [private fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields):

```js
export default class Foo {
    #bar;
    init(number){
        this.#bar = number;
    }
    getBar(){
        return this.#bar;
    }
}
```

I'm testing it in a vue component:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <div>{{bar}}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Foo from '../api/foo.js';
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      foo: new Foo(),
      bar: '',
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // doesn't work
    this.foo.init(2);
    this.bar = this.foo.getBar();
  },
}
</script>
```

But this code throws the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: attempted to set private field on non-instance
    at _classExtractFieldDescriptor (classExtractFieldDescriptor.js?06d5:3)
    at _classPrivateFieldSet (classPrivateFieldSet.js?9bd1:4)
    at Proxy.init (foo.js?c8b1:8)
    at Proxy.mounted (HelloWorld.vue?fdab:18)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6990)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6999)
    at Array.hook.__weh.hook.__weh (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:2270)
    at flushPostFlushCbs (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:7191)
    at render (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:5142)
    at mount (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3477)
```

It seems that I can't use my `init()` method on `this.foo` which is declared in my vue data member, but I can use a local variable and then set my data member:

```
  mounted() {
    // works
    const foo = new Foo();
    foo.init(2);
    this.bar = foo.getBar();
  },
```

Is this a normal behavior? Is there any ways to have `this.foo.init(2)` work?

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. Everything seems to be working fine here: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-khorana-ij02n?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, I'll look into it tomorrow. Maybe I misconfigured something.

Comment: indeed, it works with vue2 but not with vue3 : https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-chatterjee-uohy9?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [Mythos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5309299/mythos), it appeared that it works with vue2 ([example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-khorana-ij02n?file=/src/App.vue)) but not with vue3 ([example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-chatterjee-uohy9?file=/src/App.vue)).
After some digging, it looks like [private members break proxies](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/issues/106) and that [Proxy were introduced in vue3](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#how-vue-tracks-these-changes) for components' data function :

> When we return a plain JavaScript object from a component's data
> function, Vue will wrap that object in a Proxy (opens new window)with
> handlers for get and set. Proxies were introduced in ES6 and allow Vue
> 3 to avoid some of the reactivity caveats that existed in earlier
> versions of Vue.